# Copy char* to another char[]

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I've a simple question about string/char. I've tried to implement a basic system like this;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //I'll use 'char*' for socket receive buffer!
    const char* input = "This is a test!";
    char n[4];
    strncpy(n, input, 4);
    printf("%s\n%i\n", n, strlen(n));
    return 0;
}
```

And I got this output:

```
Thisd0@
7
```

What's wrong? This is a simple as a for/while loop (IDK).

Comment: strncpy must be the worst designed function in the entire C API. The OP expectations are perfectly reasonable, strncpy isn't.

Comment: @john , and thats saying a lot since there are some many bad ones :/

Comment: @john: `atoi` is pretty bad.  Returning 0 (which is probably the most common integer in existence) to indicate failure.

Comment: My suggestion (assuming C++11) is just using `std::string` and `&str[0]` if you need C access to it.

Comment: I'll make a suggestion.  You've tagged this C++, so use what C++ provides. `std::string input = "This is a test!"; std::string n = input.substr(0,4);`

Comment: @chris Is there any performance difference?

Comment: @PilawyerDev `std::string` performs much better in terms of writing bug free code. Bugs are immensely more costly than milliseconds of CPU time.

Comment: @PilawyerDev, If you can measure a performance problem due to it that can be fixed by using C strings, go ahead and don't use it, but that's unlikely to happen.

Comment: I think I got something new :) **Thanks all!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still need to put a null-terminating char (`\0`) at the end.

```
char n[5] = { '\0' }; // Initializes the array to all \0
strncpy(n, input, 4);
```

Comment: It might not be entirely clear that you are `0`-ing the *entire* array in the first line.

Comment: What a quiet simple! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `n` char needs to be 5 bytes big (4 characters + null-terminater).  You're seeing gonk afterwards because there is no null-terminator `\0`.